# Submitting Image From Form Apparently Wrong Octet

Tags: php, encoding

A simple form with an image viewer below it in the same test.php script, the image gives errors in displaying. Disabling the headers and viewing the image data on the screen, it seems to have many of the little black ? diamonds all over it so probably somehow the wrong octet is being submitted. Where does the encoding get lost and how do I fix it?

To clarify, I am not trying to upload and save the file anywhere and I am not trying to insert it into a database. I simply want the data stream to directly display itself on the screen.

Also, the conditional around the PHP code is simply so that it does nothing until it receives a file. No validation needed as this is used only locally on my development system as a test tool.

**test.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Image Functions Tester</legend>
        <p><label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToProcess" id="fileToProcess">

        <p><input name="insert" type="submit" value="Upload">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
    if (isset($_FILES['fileToProcess'])) :

        $file = $_FILES['fileToProcess'];
        $image = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);

        // TEST ConvertImage() FUNCTON HERE

        // Get the image mime type
        $mimetype = Array("1" => "image/gif",
                          "2" => "image/jpeg",
                          "3" => "image/png",
                          "6" => "image/bmp");

        // Add headers and output the image
        Header("Pragma: no-cache");
        Header('Content-type: ' . $mimetype[exif_imagetype($image)]);
        echo $image;
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gives error"? Which kind of error? Can you share the **exact** error message, and your debugging approaches?

Comment: There was simply an error that the image was invalid and could not be displayed. However, the problems were resolved some time ago (see my own answer) but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to display uploaded image. in your code I see that you are trying to validate to ensure that user submit only images. In php they are just two best method to ensure that submitted files are not virus but image

**1.) using Getimagesize Function**

**2.) Fileinfo method.**

I have implemented the validation in your code to ensure workability.

First create a directory call **uploads** where files will be uploaded and run this your update code

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Image Functions Tester</legend>
        <p><label for="image">Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="fileToProcess" id="fileToProcess">

        <p><div class="ButtonCenter">
        <input name="insert" type="submit" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['fileToProcess'])) {
$uploadDir = "uploads/";

$filename= $_FILES['fileToProcess']['name'];


$file_types=array(
'image/gif',

    'image/jpeg',

    'image/png',

'image/jpg',



'image/GIF',

    'image/JPEG',

    'image/PNG',

'image/JPG'

);




// validate image using getimagesize function 
$image_info =getimagesize($_FILES['fileToProcess']['tmp_name']);
//print_r($image_info);
$mime_image = $image_info['mime'];

// ensure the file is image via getimagesize function
if ( ! ( in_array($mime_image, $file_types) ) ) {

  echo "you can only upload images";

exit();

}




//validate image using file info function
$f = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($f, $_FILES['fileToProcess']['tmp_name']);


if ( ! ( in_array($mime, $file_types) ) ) {

  echo "You can only upload Images";

exit();

}
finfo_close($f);


if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToProcess']['tmp_name'],"$uploadDir/".$filename)) {
echo "File uploaded successfully";
echo "<img src='uploads/$filename' width='100px' height='100px'>";
}


}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for that but I don't see anything that addresses the encoding issue, which was the question. I clarified the question to say that I am not saving the file to a database and neither is it being uploaded anywhere. I am trying to display it directly to the screen from the data stream. Also, getimagesize() for fetching the mime type is very insecure which is why I did it manually. In any event, since I am working with a data stream only getimagesize() will not work and would require getimagesizefromstring().

Comment: There is no need for any kind of validation for file type as this is being used here locally on my development system as a testing tool. The conditional surrounding the image processing code is only so that it receives an image before it does anything.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting with this for two days, I just found the problem although I don't fully understand the reason it makes a difference. Apparently the form and the viewer cannot be on the same page so splitting them into two files works perfectly:

**test.php**

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_FILES['fileToProcess'])) : ?>
    <div class="PageCaption">Site Administration<hr></div>
    <form method="POST" action="testviewer.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Image Functions Tester</legend>
            <p><label for="image">Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="fileToProcess" id="fileToProcess">

            <p><div class="ButtonCenter">
            <input name="insert" type="submit" value="Upload">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form><?php 
endif; ?>
```

**testviewer.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['fileToProcess'])) :

    $file = $_FILES['fileToProcess'];
    $image = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);

    // Get the image mime type
    $mimetype = Array("1" => "image/gif",
                      "2" => "image/jpeg",
                      "3" => "image/png",
                      "6" => "image/bmp");

    // Add headers and output the image
    Header("Pragma: no-cache");
    Header('Content-type: ' . $mimetype[exif_imagetype($image)]);
    echo $image;
endif;?>
```